how to fix "'list' object is not callable" error when creating test and training sets?
I'm trying to create test and training sets using data from the Brown Corpus using the code below:
import math
from random import shuffle

sentences = brown.tagged_sents(tagset='universal') 
tag_types = list(set([token[1] for sent in sentences for token in sent]))

split_index = math.floor(0.8 * len(sentences))

sentences = list(sentences)
shuffle(sentences)

train = sentences[0:split_index]
test = sentences[split_index:]

print ('Number of train sentences: ' + str(len(train)))
print ('Number of test sentences: ' + str(len(test)))

However, both the line starting with "tag_types" and the line "sentences = list(sentences)" are producing a "'list' object is not callable" error, and I'm not sure how to fix this.
I've tried commenting out both lines, reformatting them, and renaming the variables, but I'm really not sure what's causing this problem. This code was also given in the assignment, so I'm not sure why there would be this kind of error.

It's likely that you're not sharing all your code, or that you wrote a math.py or random.py (in the same folder, or on the Python path somehow) that have an object defined in them that you called list. Avoid using keywords and other builtin identifiers as your own identifiers - this 'shadows' the original, breaking your code.

If you’re using a notebook, restart it, or evaluate del list as a one-off.

If the tag_types = ... line is throwing an error, how does the code even proceed to the sentences = ... line?

Instead of trying to describe the error, just show us the exact error traceback message.  That way we don't have to guess what you meant.

i moved the notebook out of the folder it was in and it fixed the issue, so yeah i assume i had something called list in that folder already. thank you!
